# I have changed the time zone of my blog and all times of my posts are wrong. How can I fix it?

Tags: timezones

I have changed the time zone of my WordPress blog because I have relocated. After that, all times shown on the blog are wrong.

For example, my post was published at 2021-04-22 00:22 +0800 (Hong Kong Time). I have configured the time format on my blog to include the time zone. However I have relocated to the UK so that I changed the time zone of my blog to London. Now, the time is showing at 2021-04-22 00:22 +0100 which is obviously wrong.

How can I fix it such that it can show correctly as 2021-04-21 17:22 +0100?

Comment: I'd check how your theme is reading the dates for display: in particular, is it using the post_date and post_modified or the *_gmt versions? The simplest fix might be to recompute the post_date and post_modified columns in the database from the *_gmt versions. (Take a backup first!)

Comment: However I'm surprised: I thought most hosted servers just used UTC timestamps anyway?

Comment: If you're displaying the timezone offset, like `+0800`, then why would the date and time change?

Comment: I believe all themes are using get_the_time() function in the template.

Comment: The server timestamp is not relevant. There is a time zone setting configurable in WordPress settings.